# URLSession.shared.dataTask can't download image with swedish url

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, swift3

I try to download image:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            ...

        }).resume()
```

This code works perfectly for url:

```
https://website.com/abo_beach.jpg
```

But when I try to download Swedish link:

```
https://website.com/åbo_beach.jpg
```

with letter "å", I got this error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

How can I download image from Swedish link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer by Abdelahad Darwish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877554/433373) is an improvement and perhaps fixes your particular problem (illegal characters), but in general you would want to detect these kind of errors and fail gracefully instead of risk crashing your app.

In particular, stay away from `!` on methods that return an optional value (i.e., can potentially fail) and add the necessary checks instead:

```
var urlString: String = "https://website.com/åbo_beach.jpg".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    // String can not yield a valid URL; do someting!
    return
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // ...
}).resume()
```